# Why "visual studio code" keeps crashing my Windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code, ansible

I have just started using Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

I have setup terminal to use WSL Ubuntu.

Microsoft have done a tremendous job on this. I have some extensions working very well, such as GitLens, Docker.

So here is the issue I am facing,
1. I opened a terminal WSL Ubuntu in VisualStudioCode.
2. I did git clone of my Ansible PB repo.
3. I just ran the Ansible PB and Windows crashed with blue screen.

I rebooted and ran the same Ansible playbook, the crash is consistent. 
Seems its only with some of the playbook. When I used connection=paramiko no issues.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: WSL does not support Docker. I would be shocked if VS Code worked within WSL

Comment: As a workaround, use Ansible in VM and manage it with Ansible client in WSL.

Answer (score 1):

Folks,

I will go ahead and answer my own question. Each developer's environment is different.
I did all these things to fix it,

1. Our corporate laptop has Disk encryption Bitlocker. I disabled this.
2. Cleaned up the $HOME/.vscode-server in WSL Ubuntu. I was using Remote WSL in Windows  vscode. I reinstalled all extensions. It's easy if you have MS account to reinstall.
3. Updated vscode with latest version, restart sshd service in ubuntu WSL.

So far no crash using Ansible PB without connection=paramiko, I think Bitlocker was the key here.